# Odd Websocket Error at Build Time - "Unable to Resolve websocket/lib/BufferUtil"?

Tags: node.js, meteor, websocket, npm

Even though I have Websocket installed, at build time, using the Meteor build tool, I’m getting this console error:

```
Unable to resolve some modules:

  "../build/Release/bufferutil" in /Volumes/RAM Disk/myWebApp/node_modules/websocket/lib/BufferUtil.js (os.osx.x86_64)
  "../build/default/bufferutil" in /Volumes/RAM Disk/myWebApp/node_modules/websocket/lib/BufferUtil.js (os.osx.x86_64)
  "../build/Release/validation" in /Volumes/RAM Disk/myWebApp/node_modules/websocket/lib/Validation.js (os.osx.x86_64)
  "../build/default/validation" in /Volumes/RAM Disk/myWebApp/node_modules/websocket/lib/Validation.js (os.osx.x86_64)
```

What might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is just a warning, not a fatal error.

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6601